# Join two tables and count values from second table in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have two Sheets with data like so-

`Sheet 1`:

```
      A   
  --------
1 | Name |
2 | sue  |
3 | bob  |
4 | mary |
5 | john |
```

`Sheet 2`:

```
      A            B           C        D      
  ---------------------------------------------
1 |   ID  | Asignee         | Due | Days Left |
2 | ID001 | sue, bob        |   1 |         5 |
3 | ID002 | sue, mary       |   2 |         8 |
4 | ID003 | bob             |   3 |         2 |
5 | ID004 | bob, john       |   1 |         9 |
6 | ID005 | bob, mary, john |   4 |         1 |
7 | ID006 | sue, bob        |   1 |         8 |
8 | ID007 | john, sue, mary |   2 |         6 |
```

On a 3rd sheet, I want to join and combine the data to get some totals/counts.

`Sheet 3`:

```
      A    B                 C                 D           
  ---------------------------------------------------------
1 | Name | Number Rows | Total Due | Minimum of Days Left |
2 | sue  | 4           | 6         |                    5 |
3 | bob  | 5           | 10        |                    1 |
4 | mary | 3           | 8         |                    1 |
5 | john | 3           | 7         |                    1 |
```

For the 3rd sheet:

- It has the same # of rows and values as `Sheet 1`
- Column `Sheet 3!B` is the **# of rows** in `Sheet 2` where `Sheet 2!B` **contains** `Sheet 1!A` (or `Sheet 3!A`)

  - There are 4 rows in `Sheet 2` where `Sheet 2!B` contain `sue`
  - There are 5 rows in `Sheet 2` where `Sheet 2!B` contain `bob`
  - There are 3 rows in `Sheet 2` where `Sheet 2!B` contain `bob`
  - There are 3 rows in `Sheet 2` where `Sheet 2!B` contain `bob`
- Column `Sheet 3!C` is the **total** of `Sheet 2!C` where `Sheet 2!B` **contains** `Sheet 1!A` (or `Sheet 3!A`)
- Column `Sheet 3!D` is the **smallest value** of `Sheet 2!D` where `Sheet 2!B` **contains** `Sheet 1!A` (or `Sheet 3!A`)

I've been staring at a blank sheet and am not sure where to start. I think I have to use `filter`, and `arrayformula` but I'm not sure how or where to start.

Comment: @player0 unfortunately I can't right now. At work and work Enterprise g suite won't let me share externally. I'll create a temp sheet at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♀", 1, 
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))<>"", 
 SPLIT(B2:B, ",")&"♦"&C2:C&"♦"&D2:D, )), "♀"))), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1),sum(Col2),min(Col3) 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)'',sum(Col2)'',min(Col3)''"))
```

Edit by @IMtheNachoMan to add details on why/how I think the above formula works:

- `split` the values in column `B` and concatenate the values in column `C` and column `D` with an arbritary value that is assured to not be used in any of the columns

  - because everything is wrapped in an `arrayformula`, each value from the column `B` split will get concatenated
- splitting column `B` will create an errror for rows that don't have a value in column `B`

  - so the `if` and `iferror` will check if the split will create an error and if it does it will return `null` instead of the concatenated string from the first bullet
- at this point we have one row for each row in the source table with column `B` split and concatenated with column `C` and `D`
- `join` all the rows using a second arbritary value that is assured not to be in any of the columns

  - be sure to ignore empty values
  - empty values will be there from the rows that didn't have any values in the split from the first bullet
- `split` the joined data (that doesn't have empty rows cause of the previous bullet) on the 2nd arbritary value that was used
- `transpose` it back into rows
- `trim` each row to remove spaces (not sure how/where the spaces got added though)
- `split` the column in each row with the first arbritary value
- use this as the input for a `query` call and use aggregate functions to get the data we want

[image: 0]

---

if you really need to preserve order do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2:A, 
 QUERY(SPLIT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♀", 1, 
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B, ","))<>"", 
 SPLIT(B2:B, ",")&"♦"&C2:C&"♦"&D2:D, )), "♀"))), "♦"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1),sum(Col2),min(Col3) 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)'',sum(Col2)'',min(Col3)''"), {1, 2, 3, 4}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This works. Is it okay if I edit your answer to add a detailed explanation of what/how **I think** it is doing for you to review/confirm my understanding?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan you can try :)

Comment: added. mind reviewing? i haven't broke down the second formula yet.

Comment: spaces did not get added. its a remain from B column coz values are comma+space separated

Comment: I might have to post a new question for this but if `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` are on one Spreadsheet, but I want the data in a different Spreadsheet, what would I do? Using the above formula I need to reference different ranges -- if I use `IMPORTRANGE`+`QUERY` then I won't be able to reference the individual ranges. I figured out one way by having multiple `IMPORTRANGE` statements. Thoughts? Or let me know if I should post a new question...

Comment: its doable. you just replace all ranges with `IMPORTRANGE("ID","Sheet1!A2:A")` etc. but first you need to run importrnge formulas as standalone and link the sheets. also, note that if your dataset is huge then having more importrange formulas will cause performance slowdown. in such cases is better to import what you need with just a few importrange formulas and then just refer to sheets